# Unable to extract text from textbox on specific website using iMacros

Tags: csv, extract, imacros

I am trying to match coordinates with 9062 IATA codes that I have compiled in a CSV file. I have tried to use iMacros to input the IATA codes into this website: https://openflights.org/html/apsearch and to extract the coordinates that result.

When executing the macro I do not receive an error, but none of the values are extracted to my designated CSV (the CSV file is blank).

Here is the code:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES

SET !DATASOURCE C:\REDACTED\Desktop\iatasolo.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

URL GOTO=https://openflights.org/html/apsearch
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=NAME:iatafilter CONTENT=NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=NAME:iata CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=*
TAG POS=6 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=*
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=NAME:y EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=NAME:x EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=C:\REDACTED\Desktop\macro\test2 FILE=coordinates.csv
```

Any help would be appreciated.

IATA CODE DATA: https://pastebin.com/4Ez4ids3

Comment: Hey Lora, yes I do. https://pastebin.com/4Ez4ids3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code with the sample data and the website and checked the issues.

List of Issues:

1. The input file was not getting detected. This was fixed by putting the path in quotes and using the "/" instead of "\" which is used in windows paths.
2. I have a wait of 2 seconds after the load button is clicked to give time for latitude and longitude to load.
3. Similarly output should have a different kind of format, this is what worked for me.

Please find below the working code:

```
VERSION BUILD=9030808 RECORDER=FX
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !DATASOURCE "C:/Users/Tester/Desktop/file_name.csv"
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 30
SET !EXTRACTDIALOG NO
SET !LOOP 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
URL GOTO=https://openflights.org/html/apsearch
SET !EXTRACT NULL
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:CHECKBOX FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=NAME:iatafilter CONTENT=NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=NAME:iata CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=*
TAG POS=6 TYPE=INPUT:BUTTON ATTR=*
WAIT SECONDS=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=NAME:iata EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=NAME:y EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:searchform ATTR=NAME:x EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER="C:\\Users\\Tester\\Desktop" FILE=coordinates.csv
```